# Ghostscript.NET.dll print pdf to specified printer

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, ghostscript, ghostscript.net

How to print pdf using ghostscript api.
I tried google but still not getting proper solution. Please help me how i do this task.

Comment: You didn't Google enough. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21462247/printing-pdf-using-ghostscript-net-dpi-printing-issue  |  You can use this converter if you need to: http://codeconverter.sharpdevelop.net/SnippetConverter.aspx

Comment: https://ghostscriptnet.codeplex.com/discussions/574516 | https://ghostscriptnet.codeplex.com/discussions/470946

Comment: @Visual Vincent all above example is convert pdf to image. I want to direct print pdf to printer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work for you (by using [**Ghostscript.NET**](https://ghostscriptnet.codeplex.com) wrapper):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Ghostscript.NET.Processor;

namespace Ghostscript.NET.Samples
{
    public class SendToPrinterSample : ISample
    {
        public void Start()
        {
            // YOU NEED TO HAVE ADMINISTRATOR RIGHTS TO RUN THIS CODE

            string printerName = "YourPrinterName";
            string inputFile = @"E:\__test_data\test.pdf";

            using (GhostscriptProcessor processor = new GhostscriptProcessor())
            {
                List<string> switches = new List<string>();
                switches.Add("-empty");
                switches.Add("-dPrinted");
                switches.Add("-dBATCH");
                switches.Add("-dNOPAUSE");
                switches.Add("-dNOSAFER");
                switches.Add("-dNumCopies=1");
                switches.Add("-sDEVICE=mswinpr2");
                switches.Add("-sOutputFile=%printer%" + printerName);
                switches.Add("-f");
                switches.Add(inputFile);

                processor.StartProcessing(switches.ToArray(), null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried with below suggested link code with out ghost script installation. I tried with gsdll32.dll assembly binary and GhostscriptVersionInfo. 
[link](https://ghostscriptnet.codeplex.com/discussions/465418)
Please help me how to work with native dll and managed assembly.

Comment: when printer removed it  processor.StartProcessing(switches.ToArray(), null); method stuck